# How to subscribe for child event only in YUI3 widget-parent/child?

Tags: widget, yui, yui3

Good day!

I'm trying to build hierarchical widget with YUI3 Widget-parent and widget-child and currently studying Hierarchical [ListBox Widget](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/widget/widget-parentchild-listbox.html).

I want to subscribe only to click event of the particular child that was clicked. Continuing usage example from the above page, I'm doing:

```
listbox.on("listbox:click", function(e) {...});
```

Now when I click on the "Item Three - Two" entry in the list, this event gets fired for  "Item Three - Two",  "Item Three" and root widgets. Inside that event handler, I've found no way to determine whether e.target is the original widget I've clicked on or one if its parents.

So my questions are:

1. How do I discover that I'm in event handler of the original
   widgetthat was clicked?
2. Is it possible to make clicked widget be the
   only one that fires the event?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an example fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mjhm/A6nqR/)

If you're just wanting to get the leaf node as `e.target` use:

```
listbox.on('option:click', function (e) {...
```

Subscribing to the `listbox:click` actually doesn't pick up the leaf node in my example, but it picks up the click for the two parent `listbox` ancestor widgets.

Comment: The problem is actually a big deeper. I've written about it in more depth here: [link](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=9781) and here: [link](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=9775)